# Is there any change when upgrading .Net 6 to .Net 7 in database migrations?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, database-migration

I am using the Npgsql driver and after upgrading all dependencies to version 7.0.0, I cannot fulfill any migration. I am doing some seeding in DbContext.

This is my context:

```cs
public class TransportationContext: DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Policy> Policies { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Servant> Servants { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<DiscountCode> DiscountCodes { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<DiscountCodeUser> DiscountCodeUsers { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<ServiceBaseType> ServiceBaseTypes { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<ServiceAreaType> ServiceAreaTypes { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<ServiceAreaParams> ServiceAreaParams { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<BaseNightPeriods> BaseNightPeriods { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<ServantStatus> ServantStatuses { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<ServantDailyStatistic> ServantDailyStatistics { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<CanceledTask> CanceledTasks { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<CancelReason> CancelReasons { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<CancelReasonTranslation> CancelReasonTranslations { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<RequestServant> RequestServants { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<ServantDailyOnlinePeriod> ServantDailyOnlinePeriods { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<ServantHourlyStatistic> ServantHourlyStatistics { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<TaskHourlyStatistic> TaskHourlyStatistics { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<DailyStatistic> DailyStatistics { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<ActiveRole> ActiveRoles { get; set; } = null!;

    [Obsolete("Obsolete")]
    static TransportationContext()
    {
        NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<DiscountCodeTypeEnum>();
        NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<TaskStatusEnum>();
        NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<RequestTypeEnum>();
        NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<RequestStatusEnum>();
    }

    public TransportationContext(DbContextOptions<TransportationContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(o => o.UseNetTopologySuite());
        // optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("postgis");
        
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<DiscountCodeTypeEnum>();
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<TaskStatusEnum>();
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<RequestTypeEnum>();
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<RequestStatusEnum>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Policy>().HasData(GetPolicies());
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasData(GetBaseRoles());

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Policy>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Roles)
            .WithMany(r => r.Policies)
            .UsingEntity(j => j.HasData(GetRolePolicies(1)));

        modelBuilder.Entity<DiscountPeriods>(builder =>
        {
            // StartTime is a TimeOnly property and time on database
            builder.Property(x => x.StartTime)
                .HasConversion<TimeOnlyConverter, TimeOnlyComparer>();

            // EndTime is a TimeOnly property and time on database
            builder.Property(x => x.EndTime)
                .HasConversion<TimeOnlyConverter, TimeOnlyComparer>();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ServantDailyStatistic>(builder =>
        {
            // StartTime is a TimeOnly property and time on database
            builder.Property(x => x.Date)
                .HasConversion<DateOnlyConverter, DateOnlyComparer>();
        });

        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            //If the actual entity is an auditable type. 
            if (typeof(Auditable).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                //This adds (In a reflection type way), a Global Query Filter
                //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters
                //That always excludes deleted items. You can opt out by using dbSet.IgnoreQueryFilters()
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
                var deletedCheck =
                    Expression.Lambda(
                        Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "DeletedAt"), Expression.Constant(null)),
                        parameter);
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(deletedCheck);
            }
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I want to add this property in migration

```cs
public class RequestServant : Auditable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
>   public bool IsOnline {get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public int ServantId { get; set; }
```

This gives me an error every time:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: CreatedAt
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.AddSeedData(IEntityType entityType, Dictionary`2 identityMaps, EntityState initialState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.TrackData(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDataOperations(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: CreatedAt
```

Here are the other data context methods for data seeding and global query filter:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<Policy> GetPolicies()
{
    var allPolicies = Enum.GetValues<PolicyEnum>();
    return allPolicies.Select(p => new Policy { Id = (int)p, Name = p.ToString() });
}

private static IEnumerable<Policy> GetBaseRoles()
{
    var allPolicies = Enum.GetValues<BaseRoles>();
    return allPolicies.Select(p => new Policy { Id = (int)p, Name = p.ToString() });
}

private static IEnumerable<object> GetRolePolicies(int roleId)
{
    var allPolicies = Enum.GetValues<PolicyEnum>();
    return allPolicies.Select(p => new { PoliciesId = (int)p, RolesId = roleId });
}

private void AddTimestamps()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(x => x.Entity is Auditable && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow; // current datetime

        if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((Auditable)entity.Entity).CreatedAt = now;
            ((Auditable)entity.Entity).UpdatedAt = now;
        }

        ((Auditable)entity.Entity).UpdatedAt = now;
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any solution on the internet.

Update: I downgraded Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore from 7.0.0 to 6.6 and all related packages, then the migration was built successfully. So, it looks like a bug. I will try to find the issue on GitHub or create one.

Comment: Nothing in the code you show is related to `CreatedAt` in the exception message.

Comment: yes, I haven't added any createdAt key .Because of that i don't know what's the problem

Comment: Show to us the `GetPolicies()`, `GetBaseRoles()` methods and `Policy` and `Role` classes, pls.

Comment: I mean: where is `CreatedAt` in your code? If it's in the exception message, the obvious thing to do is to find which part of the code contains the property. EF internally tries to add it to a dictionary. It's not related to database keys.

Comment: I added the code where  add CreatedAt and UpdateAt to every entity

Comment: No, that's where you assign them. Show your Auditable entity and everything else you do with it. Create a [mre].

Comment: Looks like a bug if it worked in previous versions. You better post this reproducible example at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues (but please first check if there's not a similar issue yet). We can't help you here.

Comment: everything worked well and I did many database migrations in this project before, until I upgraded to .Net 7 and it still works fine except for the migration that gave me the above error