# EF Core, when updating database I get: "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key '17736' was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am fairly new to .NET and Entity Framework Core, and I am trying to build a simple backend with REST endpoints for querying some items.

I am currently stock with an error that I haven't been able to solve after doing quite some research:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key '17736' was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.set_CharacterSetIndex(Int32 value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField[] columns)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId, Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

The error occurred after trying to reset my migrations, which I did by deleting the tables generated by EF Core, deleting the `__EFMigrationsHistory`  table, and deleting the migrations folder in my code.

After that I re-ran:

```
dotnet ef migrations add addItemTable
dotnet ef database update
```

The error log above came from the latter command.

I am not sure how to fix this. I even tried to delete the full database and re-running the commands.

If anyone has an idea of how to fix this please let me know.

EDIT:

For reference here is my .csproj with dependencies:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>True</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.10"/>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.22"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.10"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.10"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: can you try the command now in this order `dotnet ef database update
dotnet ef migrations add addItemTable
dotnet ef database update`

Comment: @viveknuna I just tried it. Running ` dotnet ef update `, even without migrations folder, gives me the same error

Comment: This is not about migration . I think this is about a dictionary. Do you have dictionary ? Error say there is no such a key "17736" . Do you have a data seed method ?

Comment: If you deleted the database, then delete the migrations as well.

Comment: @firatt_ See the stack trace. It's internal EF code. It's propably a bug. Therefore knowing the EF version is important. There is at least [one other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74500340/861716) in the same area.

Comment: @GertArnold, The EF version is 3.1.10. I just updated the post with my .csproj

Comment: However, notice I use 8.0.22 of MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: You emptied the database.  The dictionary is the primary key of a table in the database.  The exception is indicating the value 17736 is not in the database which is expected if you emptied the database.

Comment: But @jdweng, how does it still have a reference to the old database if I deleted migrations and snapshot?

Comment: @jdweng, I want to start afresh with a new database

Comment: So if you have an empty database why are you looking for a value 17736?  Migration takes the c# classes and create table/fields in the database.  So after you removed the old database you ran migration which created an empty database.

Comment: I don't manually do it, but it happens when I run `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: You have just deleted the database. Therefore, there is nothing to update! Completely delete the folder of migrations remaining from the last time. Then [Create your first migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#create-your-first-migration)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I have done that already. Just tried again. Same error.

Comment: Try to use [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). It is more mature than official provider.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks a lot! Everything works with Pomelo, so I appreciate that answer! They also have a `UseMysql` method, but notice the difference in capitalization if you were initially using `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` where it is  `UseMySQL`

Comment: @WillGates, also note that Pomelo is true `async` provider, while Oracle still not implemented asynchronous version of their provider.